# ComplexExpand and Arg function

Tags: complex

Why does the command `ComplexExpand[Arg[a]]` gives `Arg[a]` instead of 0? Isn't it that `ComplexExpand` supposed to assume all unspecified variable to be real, and the argument of real variable is 0?

Comment: `In[1328]:= Arg[-1]

Out[1328]= \[Pi]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `ComplexExpand` itself does not know what is `a`, complex, real and so on. One needs to instruct Mma about it. For example,

```
    Simplify[ComplexExpand[Arg[a]], a > 0]

(*  0  *)
```

Here is another example:

```
    Simplify[ComplexExpand[Arg[a]], a < 0]

(*  \[Pi]  *)
```

On the other hand, if one does not fix the sign of a, but only that it is Real, Mma assumes that it can have the both signs and leaves the both possibilities:

```
Simplify[ComplexExpand[Arg[a]], a \[Element] Reals]

(*  Arg[a]  *)
```

Even more this is valid, if a may be complex:

```
Simplify[ComplexExpand[Arg[a]]]

(*  Arg[a] *)
```

Have fun!

Comment: `ComplexExpand[Arg[a], TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im}]`

Comment: Actually `ComplexExpand` (per documentation) assumes all variables are real valued unless they appear in the optional second argument. What it does not know is whether they are positive or negative.